# GCM not waking up device when message received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Yes, there have been questions about this before, but they all date back to 2012 and even further back, using a different version of GCM.

I'm on GCM 3.0, following the guide provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

The provide a sample manifest like this:

```
<manifest package="com.example.gcm" ...>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application ...>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

By comparison, here is mine:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application...

    <service android:name=".service.NotificationListenerService"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service android:name=".service.GcmTokenListenerService"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceId"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service android:name=".service.GcmRegistrationService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <!-- Receivers -->

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myapp"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

It looks just like theirs, but my phone doesn't handle incoming notifications until after the phone wakes up. If I send a message to myself, it will remain dormant, until I unlock the phone and then it immediately begins to process the incoming message.

Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `onMessage()` is called when the message is received on the device through GCM. The wakelock is not invoked at that stage, it does when the `onStart()` is called. The best bet here is to embed the code of the WAKELOCK inside the onMessage() call.

Here is the code:

```
PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "bbbb");
wl.acquire();
```

That would go inside the *onMessage()*instead of *HandleMessage()*

Hope this helps!